# Cron Job $_SERVER issue

Tags: php, cron

I want to run a cron job. My application is developed in PHP and Mysql.

In browser if i use `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` in coding, it works fine. But if I use the same thing in cron job it is giving errors.

Can any body give suggestion to fix this?

Comment: please provide some error-message of some kind. Maybe $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] undefined due to the cron script is not defining any HTTP_HOST, like browsers do ? You could test it with isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])

Comment: php >= 5.3.0 use gethostname()

Comment: @nick if a website is hosted at a shared hosting, the `gethostname()` returns the host of the server like `s1.myhosting.com`

Answer (score 20):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not populated when running it from a cronjob, the file is not accessed via HTTP.

You will either have to hardcode the Host or pass it via a command line argument and access it via the `$_SERVER['argv']` array.

Comment: Good answer.
CLI scripts have $argv and $argc globals that you can access, so there is no need to use $_SERVER.

Comment: `$argv` is not available in functions without the global-keyword. `$_SERVER` is superglobal.

Answer (score 7):

When php is executed on the command line, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is (of course) not available.

You can just suppress the error using the `@` sign or be a bit more cautious using a construct line:

```
$host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'CLI';
```

Answer (score 7):

Try running cron job with curl .. It will populate your $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

syntax on linux is like

```
curl http://yourdomain/yourfile.php
```

Comment: This was the most straightforward solution in my mind, so long as your file is at a public-facing URL. AronCederholm also made a similar suggestion but props to @alwaysLearn for answering it right to the point. This worked perfect for me.

Comment: Be careful using this - typically with cron jobs, you want to run them at specific times. Putting them on a public domain like this, allows everyone and anyone to run your job whenever, simply by just going to the URL.

Answer (score 6):

As previously stated, $_SERVER is not present when you run php via php-cli.

Though, there is an option to run your cron'd scripts in php-cgi, where you will have $_SERVER. If you curl to a local web server, then $_SERVER will be populated.

```
$ cat /etc/cron.daily/mydailyphpwork
/usr/bin/curl http://domain.tld/path/to/cron-script.php &> /dev/null
```

**However**, I think you should indeed stick with the solutions proposed by TimWolla or DerVO, unless  you really need this behaviour.

Pros:

- You will get all $_SERVER variables set as expected.
- If you need to rewrite a lot of code with if-else's this might be preferred as you don't need to change any code.

Cons:

- It is kind of a workaround and probably means a slight increase in cpu load.

Answer (score 4):

Adding hard coded args into the crontab didn't help as I need it to be sensitive to different environments

So >= PHP 5.3.0 you can use `gethostname()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: it gives me "web" :(

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the option of just defining any required values for the _SERVER array in another file and then just including that.  This is the quickest way I've found to run a normally cgi-based php script from the cli for quick test/debugging purposes.

Eg, file `cron_server_wrapper.php`:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = "localhost";
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = "localhost";
$_SERVER['REMOVE_ADDR'] = "10.20.30.40";
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "/";
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = "/crontab-foo";
```

Then run:

```
/usr/bin/php -B "require 'path/to/cron_server_wrapper.php'" -E "require 'my_php_cron_script.php';" < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hard code the value of `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` if it is empty, or you can perform some other check.

Answer (score 0):

If [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is supported on your server, you can change your cronjob from

```
15 * * * * php -q /path/to/your/cron/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
15 * * * * wget -qO- --no-check-certificate "https://example.com/cron/script.php"
```

Be sure to limit the number of tries, and the time limit.

Consult [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for the available options.