# PHP CLI HTTP_HOST alternative

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

I have a script that I want to run via cron. I work on the script in a dev environment like...

http://dev.domain.com

then move to production...

http://prod.domain.com

Each of these use different user/pass info for PDO, so I've been exploding the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] global then checking for the "dev" or "prod" part to set my $PDO object:

```
$hostArray = explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if($hostArray[0] == 'dev' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '1.2.3.4'){
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev_db", "devu", "devp");
}
elseif($hostArray[0] == 'prod' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '1.2.3.5'){
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prod_db", "produ", "prodp");
}
// etc.
```

I understand this isn't going to work in CLI and read the following: [Cron Job $_SERVER issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128488/cron-job-server-issue)

I am not sure what, if anything is available though to know which server is running the script.

In this case, all the domains are running off the same physical server with a common /home/dev or /home/prod structure. They have different IPs and are set up via cPanel as different instances.

**EDIT**

Using RiggsFolly's suggestion I looked at what was in the environment var by trying

```
print_r($_ENV);
exit();
```

Then running the script from CL with > tmp-debug.txt on the end. Viewing this file I was able to see some variables. They looked to be the same as the $_SERVER ones I was able to see before as well, but the HTTP_HOST one was not not there.

What I've got working now is the following...

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    ... code from above...
}
elseif(isset($_SERVER['argc']) && isset($_SERVER['PWD'])) {

    $hostArray = explode("/",$_SERVER['PWD']);

    if($hostArray[2] == 'devsite'){
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev_db", "devu", "devp");
    }
    elseif($hostArray[2] == 'prodsite'){
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prod_db", "produ", "prodp");
    }
}
```

This setup works with my server having

```
/home/devsite
```

and

```
/home/prodsite/
```

set up. I don't know if there's any issue with doing this for portability or security. It does work though.

Comment: You do have access to $_SERVER and the Environment using `getenv()` are either of those any use to you. Of course there is always the `argv`, `argc` parameters so you could use `script.php LIVE` and `script.php TEST`