# laravel swift-mailer exception "Expected response code 250 but got an empty response" using gmail smtp-relay (database queue driver)

Tags: laravel, smtp, queue, gmail, swiftmailer

the gmail smtp-relay works fine using the sync driver, but if we queue the email we this error. cleared config, cache, & restarted queue workers. tested in prod and dev, same results

```
[2021-01-24 20:04:22] production.ERROR: Expected response code 250 but got an empty response {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Expected response code 250 but got an empty response at /home/****/****/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:448)
```

were wondering is this because of serialization and something is not making it through that process???
using latest stable release of laravel >8.0. gmail smtp is authenticating just fine, per why the sync driver sends emails easily. maybe there needs to be a timeout on the queue jobs so they dont barrage gmail so quickly? also our code works fine using sendgrid for example as the smtp relay. thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue, everything work on local end, but on live environment, we are getting the error, it used to work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-swift-mailer-exception-expected-response-code-250-but-got-an-empty-response-using-gmail-smtp-relay-database-queue-driver

Update your AppServiceProvider.php

add this inside boot();

```
// Fix for SwiftMailer Service; 

$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] = "your.domain.name";
```

Comment: it is working...but, can i know why?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for the 2 previous Answers

1. if $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] is the solution:

- When you are using cron
- The reason is that $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] is null when cron is executed. $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] is usually only defined for http access.
- Example implementation (laravel):

```php
if (!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
            $url = config('env.APP_URL');
            $domain = mb_ereg_replace("http(s)? ://", "", $url);
            $domainParts = explode('/', $domain);
            ini_set('server_name', count($domainParts) > 0 ? $domainParts[0] : $domain)
        }
```

- References :

  - [Cron Job $_SERVER issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128488/cron-job-server-issue)
  - https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/992

2. if 'local_domain' is the solution

- When you have a mailhost setting of `MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.gmail.com` in your laravel project
- The reason is that if `local_domain' is not set, the protocol for mail communication with Gmail will be` EHLO [127.0.0.1]` and the communication will be disconnected.
- By the way, I used gmail->gmail alias and did not need `relay` in the first place, so I solved the problem by setting `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`.
- References:

  - https://blog.trippyboy.com/2021/laravel/laravel-expected-response-code-250-but-got-an-empty-response/

I had to deal with both of them because of cron messaging and `MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.gmail.com` in my environment.
I hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For users of **smtp-relay.gmail.com**, if you use localhost/127.0.0.1 as domain during developments, you probably need to change the domain name to use in `EHLO` command to begin the transaction. I solved this by adding `&local_domain=dev.mydomain.tld` at the and of my DSN.

```
smtp://smtp-relay.gmail.com:587?encryption=tls&local_domain=dev.mydomain.tld&...
```

For SwiftMailer Symfony bundle (since 2.4.0), you can set the [`local_domain` config parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#local-domain):

```yaml
// config/packages/dev/swiftmailer.yaml
swiftmailer:
    ...
    local_domain: dev.mydomain.tld
```